# tmux compilation error in andLinux (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I'm running andLinux which is based on Ubuntu Jaunty. I'm trying to compile tmux 1.3 on that system and I get the following error message. I've already installed libevent-dev.

```
server.o: In function `server_start':
server.c:(.text+0x31b): undefined reference to `event_reinit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tmux] Error 1
```

Comment: I just found out that libevent-dev that comes in ubuntu repository wasn't new enough. It worked fine after I installed the latest version of libevent from source. Remember to remove the libevent-dev if you've already installed it via apt-get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amjith answered his own question:

> I just found out that libevent-dev that comes in ubuntu repository
>   wasn't new enough. It worked fine after I installed the latest version
>   of libevent from source. Remember to remove the libevent-dev if you've
>   already installed it via apt-get.